# How can I determine the canonical path of a file without following symbolic links?

Tags: java, io, filesystems, nio, symlink

Assume I have the following `java.io.File` and the corresponding `java.nio.file.Path` objects:

```java
final String windir = "WINNT";
final String comspec = "cmd.exe";
final File absoluteFile = new File(format("C:\\./foo/../bar/../%s/./././././SYSTEM32/../system/../System32/%s", windir, comspec)).getAbsoluteFile();
final Path absolutePath = absoluteFile.toPath();
```

Now, I want to determine the *canonical* path, i. e. remove any `.` or `..` path entries, so that the resulting path is `C:\WINNT\System32\cmd.exe`.

`java.io.File.getCanonicalPath()` is fine, except that it follows symbolic links on *Unices* which I would like to avoid.

`java.nio.file.Path.toRealPath(NOFOLLOW_LINKS)`, on the other hand, returns the canonical path *without* following symbolic links, but it throws a `java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException`.

How can I determine the canonical path of a file

- in a safe way (so that no exceptions are thrown in case the file doesn't exist),
- in a platform-independent way, and
- without following symbolic links?

The only solution I have found so far is falling back to the old `java.io` API:

```
@NonNull Path toCanonicalPath(final @NonNull Path path) throws IOException {
    try {
        /*
         * Fails for nonexistent files.
         */
        return path.toRealPath(NOFOLLOW_LINKS);
    } catch (final NoSuchFileException ignored) {
        /*
         * This one is fine except it always follows symbolic links on Unices.
         */
        return path.toFile().getCanonicalFile().toPath();
    } catch (final FileSystemException ignored) {
        /*
         * Thrown when there's a file/directory conflict, e. g.
         * for a non-existent file "foo/bar", "foo" already
         * exists and is a symlink, not a directory. In this
         * case, we can't use the File#getCanonicalFile() call.
         */
        return path.toAbsolutePath();
    }
}
```

Is there any less ugly approach?

Comment: I don't understand how you can get a canonical path *without* following symbolic links.  [It's *defined* as "resolving symbolic links"](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#getCanonicalPath()).  (OK, it's also defined as "unique", which may not be true on Unix and Unix-like systems...)

Comment: @AndrewHenle "Canonical" in terms of removing any `.` or `..` path entries, i. e. I want the **shortest absolute** path (yet without symlink resolution).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`path.toAbsolutePath().normalize()` actually did the trick.

Consider we have a `/var/spool/mail` symlink pointing to `/var/mail`:

```
final Path path = Paths.get("/var/./spool/../spool//mail/./");
System.out.println(path.toAbsolutePath().normalize());
System.out.println(path.toRealPath(NOFOLLOW_LINKS));
```

In the above example, in both cases the canonical path is printed with symlinks left unresolved:

```
/var/spool/mail
/var/spool/mail
```